# bluemix docker-compose String indices must be integers

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, docker-compose

I'm trying to upload two containers to Bluemix using docker-compose:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-bluemix.yml up -d
```

My `docker-compose-bluemix.yml` file is:

```
api:
   image: registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/mycompany/java
   container_name: java-identity-verification-sdk-container
   ports:
    - 8080:8080
   volumes:
    - java-identity-verification-sdk:/data
   links:
    - mongo
mongo:
   image: registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/mycompany/mongo
   container_name: mongo-identity-verification-sdk-container
   volumes:
    - mongo-identity-verification-sdk:/data/db
   ports:
    - 27017:27017
```

There are no special characters in `docker-compose-bluemix.yml` (like tabs).
The images were previously uploaded to Bluemix, and the two volumes `java-identity-verification-sdk` and `mongo-identity-verification-sdk` were also created.

I get this error:

```
Starting ongo-identity-verification-sdk-container
Creating java-identity-verification-sdk-container

ERROR: for api  string indices must be integers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 64, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 116, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 876, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 416, in up
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 66, in parallel_execute
TypeError: string indices must be integers
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Why?
(by the way, why does it say "Starting ongo-identity-verification-sdk-container"? it should be "mongo", not "ongo")

Answer (score 0):

The error message is Compose's way of saying "something went wrong".

From looking at the compose file, my guess is that you need to declare the volumes as external, so that compose uses the ones already there instead of trying to create them.  (This is presuming that you've precreated the volumes with `cf ic volume create` - if you haven't, you need to do that first as well)

e.g. add a stanza like:

```
volumes:
  java-identity-verification-sdk:
    external: true
  mongo-identity-verification-sdk:
    external: true
```

as to the missing first letter - looks like a bug.